# Нужно сделать кредитный калькулятор используй цикл for

Tags: java, циклы, калькулятор

В цикле на каждом шаге итерация должна становиться меньше но почему то после второй строчки значение остается неизменным.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HipotecalCalculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double PERCENTS = 2.2;
    // System.out.println("сумма кредита ");
    double credit = 5000;//input.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("первый взнос ");
    double firstPayment = 1000;// input.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("Срок ");
    double paymentTerm = 12;//input.nextInt();
    double leftToPay = credit - firstPayment;
    double Z = PERCENTS / 100 / paymentTerm;
    double linearProcent = leftToPay * Z;
    System.out.format("Линейный процент %.2f\n", linearProcent);
    double payPerMonth = linearProcent + (leftToPay / paymentTerm);

    for (double i = leftToPay; i > 0; i -= payPerMonth) {

         payPerMonth= linearProcent + (leftToPay / paymentTerm);//340.67


        System.out.format("Проц %-6.2fМес %-8.2fОст %-8.2f\n", linearProcent, payPerMonth, i);
        linearProcent -= linearProcent - (leftToPay - payPerMonth) * Z;

    }
  }
}
```

Вот то что выводит код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас здесь ерунда какая-то: linearProcent -= linearProcent - (leftToPay - payPerMonth) * Z;

Comment: Как я это вижу..  
7.33-=7.33-(4000-340.67)*0.0018
7.33-=7.33-6.71
7.33-=0.62
от всего этого я жду что в следующем цикле linerProcent будет равен 6.71 и эта строчка будет выглядеть вот так:
6.71-=6.71-(3659.33-340.04)*0.0018
6.71-=6.71-5.97
6.71-=0.67

Я ведь правильно понимаю что в случае 7.33-=0.62 это 7.33 в следующем цикле должно быть 6.71?

Answer (score 2):

Строка

```
linearProcent -= linearProcent - (leftToPay - payPerMonth) * Z;
```

в большинстве случаев (кроме переполнения, Nan, Infinity, null) эквивалентна:

```
linearProcent = linearProcent - (linearProcent - (leftToPay - payPerMonth) * Z);
```

раскроем скобки, сократим:

```
linearProcent = (leftToPay - payPerMonth) * Z;
```

Ни `leftToPay`, ни `payPerMonth` в цикле не изменяются. Соответственно, `linearProcent` в первой итерации принимает значение, которое в дальнейшем не изменяется.

Задумку я не понял, но название `leftToPay` предполагает, что значение должно по-месяцам изменяться, а оно в коде всегда 4000.

Comment: Подскажите что надо сделать что бы payPerMonth изменялась?
И... как в комментарии на другую строку переходить?

Comment: Чтобы она изменялась ей нужно присвоить новое значение. Какое именно Вам лучше знать. Я лишь понял, почему значение не изменяется. В комментах перенос строки по-моему делать нельзя. Если хотите дополнить вопрос информацией, отредактируйте его (для этого под вопросом есть ссылка ["править"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/631887/edit))

Comment: Не понимаю почему не изменяется leftToPay, он ведь выводит измененные значения, на картинке ведь оно.

Comment: @Max на картинке в третьей колонке выводится счетчик цикла `i` как видно в строке вывода: `System.out.format("Проц %-6.2fМес %-8.2fОст %-8.2f\n", linearProcent, payPerMonth, i);`